# Confused about writing this C++ function

Tags: c++

This is last homework problem and I'm a little confused about it.

Using the following code:

```
class Order
{
public:
  Order();
  void addItem(string name, double price);

private:
  static const int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
  string itemNames[MAX_ITEMS];
  int numItems;  // # of items actually stored
  double totalPrice;
};

const int TABLES = 10;
const int SEATS = 4;
Order diningRoom[TABLES][SEATS];
```

Write a function that adds a free dessert to all orders in array `diningRoom`. Then, write a call to that function passing the array."

A prototype for `addItem` already exists, but it does not take an array. I'm not sure if the question asking me to alter it or create a new function. Also in the function I know you would loop through all the elements of the array but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: You should receive the name of the item and the price, and then you should add that in all the orders of diningRoom, iterating each Orded and adding that free item to each table, i mean calling the method in each iteration

Comment: create a new function

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm guessing you will want to write this in a new function which accepts `Orders dR[][]` as an argument.

```
for(int t = 0; t < TABLES; ++t)
{
    for(int s = 0; s < SEATS; ++s)
    {
        dR[t][s].addItem("ice cream", 0.0);
    }
}
```